# Mysql/PHP - account chart - summarization in the parent account

Tags: php, mysql, relationship, hierarchical-data

I'm facing some troubles trying to solve this. I have an account chart and I want to summarize the money column. My table 'category' has an auto relathionsip:

```
category_table
- id
- parent_id
- category
```

** I don't know how deep is the account chart. It could have 1,2,3,4,5...multiple levels.

Here's an example:

**What I Want:**

```
Category Name           |$
-------------------------------
Category 1              |160.00
    Category 1.1        |130.00
        some expense    | 50.00
        some expense    | 80.00
    Category 1.2        | 30.00
        some expense    | 10.00
        some expense    | 20.00
-------------------------------
Category 2              |160.00
    Category 2.1        |150.00
        some expense    |100.00
        some expense    |150.00
    Category 2.1        | 70.00
        some expense    | 50.00
        some expense    | 20.00
-------------------------------
```

**What I have:**

```
Category Name           |$
-------------------------------
Category 1              |  0.00
    Category 1.1        |  0.00
        some expense    | 50.00
        some expense    | 80.00
    Category 1.2        |  0.00
        some expense    | 10.00
        some expense    | 20.00
-------------------------------
Category 2              |  0.00
    Category 2.1        |  0.00
        some expense    |100.00
        some expense    |150.00
    Category 2.1        |  0.00
        some expense    | 50.00
        some expense    | 20.00
-------------------------------
```

I've tried this recursive function in php, but it didn't work =/

```
function display_children($parent) {
    $sql = "SELECT c.id, c.category,
                   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM category c1 WHERE c1.parent_id = c.id) As Total,
                   (SELECT SUM(p.value) FROM payables p WHERE p.category_id = c.id) As TotalToPay
            FROM category c
            WHERE c.parent_id = {$parent}
            ORDER BY c.category";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $ret = "<ul>";
    $totalcategory = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($row['Total'] > 0) {
            $totalcategory = $totalcategory + (empty($row['TotalToPay']) ? 0 : $row['TotalToPay']);
            $ret .= "<li><a href='#" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['category'] . " - " . $totalcategory . "</a>";
            $ret .= display_children($row['id']);
            $ret .= "</li>";
        } elseif ($row['Total']==0) {
            $totalcategory = ($totalcategory + empty($row['TotalToPay']) ? 0 : $row['TotalToPay']);
            $ret .= "<li><a href='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['category'] . " - " . $totalcategory . "</a></li>";
        } else;
    }
    $ret .= "</ul>";
    return $ret;
}
echo display_children(0);
```

It shows me:

```
Category 1 - 0
    Category 1.1 - 0
    Category 1.2 - 0
        expense 1 - 25.90
        expense 2 - 0
        expense 3 - 3.80
Category 2 - 0
    Category 2.1 - 0
    Category 2.2 - 0
    Category 2.3 - 0
Category 3 - 0
    Category 3.1 - 52.00
```

...Any idea? 
...thanks :)

Comment: Show us the recursive function you tried.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a maximum depth like 3 you can do it with a single query like this:

```
SELECT c1.dollar + c2.dollar2 + c3.dollar AS dollar_sum
FROM category_table c1
LEFT JOIN category_table c2 ON c1.id = c2.parent_id
LEFT JOIN category_table c3 ON c2.id = c3.parent_id
```

if you don't know the max-depth of your hierarchy you can indeed use a recusrive function in php like this

```
function getSum($parent = null) {


    if ($parent === null) {

        $rows = // SELECT id, dollar FROM category_table WHERE parent_id IS NULL;

    } else {

        $rows = // SELECT id, dollar FROM category_table WHERE parent_id = $parent;
    }

    foreach ($rows as &$row) {

        $children = getSum($row->id);
        foreach ($children as $child) {

            $row->dollar += $child->dollar;
        }
    }

    return $rows;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..but I don't know how deep is the account chart. It could have multiple levels. =/

Comment: I tried using your function, but it didn't help me...maybe I didn't understand your point of view.